# What is the order of tefillot for Yom Ha’atzma’ut?

Tags: tefilla, yom-haatzmaut

For those communities that mark Yom Ha’atzma’ut (in any way) what changes (if any) are made to the order of all three *tefillot* of the day?

I am aware of various changes made in various communities (e.g. reciting certain psalms before *arvit*, reciting an expanded *pesukei dezimra* before *shacharit*, reciting *hallel* (with or without a blessing, during or after *shacharit*), omitting *tachanun*, reciting *selichot*, reading a pseudo-*haftarah*.)

I’m seeking as comprehensive (and sourced) an answer as possible.

Comment: https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/yom-haatzmaut-yom-yerushalayim-mahzor-compact.html https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/yom-haatzmaut-liturgy/

Comment: Check out a yom haatzmaut machzor